# Using QT to monitor a Process?

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I want to monitor a process(running in OS)[lets say notebook] using C++ and QT. Currently for windows I am using

```
bool running(LPCSTR Processname)
//function to monitor the process
{
HWND hwnd = FindWindowEx(0, 0,Processname, 0);

    if (hwnd != 0)//checks if the process is running
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}
```

To monitor a process in windows and it is working fine but I want to write a program using QT, how can I do it?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Unless you launch your process from Qt, you cannot perform such monitoring...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if the question is strictly Qt-related. The monitor you want to implement is related to system programming and it requires a bit low-level knowledge on the topic.
As far as you use Windows API to monitor a windows process, you might also check how to do that for other OS.
On Linux you would like to check /proc file system where you can find everything about each running process.

... OR ... 
execute and parse the output from a command line:
On windows: tasklist
On Linux: ps

Answer (score 0):

Read the [Getting Started Tutorial](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/gettingstartedqt.html) and get used to Qt.

If you know how to create a basic Gui you can display the Status of your Thread using e.g. a QLabel.

If you want to do the Process Monitoring itself using Qt I am afraid that this is afaik not possible as QProcess only supports Processes that you spawned yourself.